# Should we bring back the user to the ABC mode on the SmartPhone keyboard automatically after they have entered some symbols/numbers/punctuation?

Tags: layout, keyboard, symbols, smartphone, keyboard-layout

Should we bring back the user to the ABC mode on the SmartPhone keyboard automatically after they have entered some symbols/numbers/punctuation marks?

Comment: In what context?

Comment: ooh, depends on what the user is doing. Snapping back to ABC can be annoying if typing a number, but good in other situations. The tricky thing is inferring what the user is doing based on what they have already typed.

Comment: Make sure you don't frustrate native behavior. Some phones have similar functionality build in. Users get used to this behavior and will anticipate on this.

Comment: I think the trick is figuring out when **some** of those characters is enough. If I'm told to enter an 8 digit phone-number, I might be happy if it kicks me back to ABC. On the other hand, if I made a typo, I'm going to be real annoyed when it kicks me back

Answer (score 1):

I would not consider this being a user preference where you need to go back to a default state.
I think it's more of a contextual thing where you set the fields to the proper type so that the corresponding keyboard shows up. For email, you'd set the type to "email" and the associated keyboard would automatically be used (it would contain the ., the .com, the @, etc.)